# flask whooshalchemy error : ModuleNotFoundError : no module named " flask.ext "

Tags: python, flask

When i type this  command in cmd(for creating the sqlite database tables) : from my_python_file 
 import db. it says :- ModuleNotFoundError: no moudle named 'flask.ext'. i have already installed flask whooshalchemy. Please anyone help !!

**Here's the code**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy 
import flask_whooshalchemy as wa

app = Flask(__name__)


app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = r'sqlite:///D:\\blog\\mydb.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True
app.config['WHOOSH_BASE'] = 'whoosh'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Post(db.Model):
    __searchable__ = []
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100))
    content = db.Column(db.Stirng(1000))

wa.whoosh_index(app, Post)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('home.html', title=title)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```